# How do I sort based on one parameter, then another in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have managed to write code which will automatically sort data once an option from a drop down has been selected. This code is as follows:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Range("A7:AF200").Sort key1:=Range("D7:D200"), _
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A7:AF" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("D7:D" & lastrow), _
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Job List").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Job List").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D:D"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
    "Pre-Design,Design,Tender,Construction,Post Construction", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Job List").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A7:AE9999")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
    End With

    End Sub
```

However, after the job list has been sorted by Custom Order, I need the data to then be sorted ascending by Job Number inputted in cells A7:A

For example:

- 110.05 ClientABC Pre-Design
- 21.02 ClientXYZ  Pre-Design
- 84.10 ClientNEW Pre-Design

Becomes

- 21.02 ClientXYZ  Pre-Design
- 84.10 ClientNEW Pre-Design
- 110.05 ClientABC Pre-Design

Automatically

Comment: you get that those are three sort operations that do almost exactly the same thing ...?

Comment: Apparently not, my coding education goes back to a short "beginners" class in University 5 years ago. Have not used it since!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting on multiple columns can be done by adding an extra sort

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Range("A7:AF200").Sort key1:=Range("D7:D200"), _
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A7:AF" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("D7:D" & lastrow), _
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Job List").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Job List").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D:D"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
    "Pre-Design,Design,Tender,Construction,Post Construction", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Job List").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A7:A9999"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Job List").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A7:AE9999")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
    End With

    End Sub
```